# Вопрос про практике разработки web проектов в комманде

Tags: laravel

Если использовать для разработки отдельный девелоп сервер, каким образом лучше создавать хосты под него example.dev или просто на дев сервере создать такую же структуру каталогов и конфигов как на продакшене и в на локальной машине для разработке просто переопределить значения в файле hosts, косается конкретно движка laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще разворачивают dev окружение идентичное prod для удобства тестирования в условиях максимально приближенных к боевым.

Да, нужно как то резолвить DNS имена проектов (дев, прод). Тут лучше всего развернуть кеширующий DNS сервер и прописать там же нужные локальные имена dev окружения к примеру example.com (prod), а example.local будет ссылаться на девелоперский сервер.

Таким образом можно разграничить имена и не заморачиваться с прописанием хостов на каждой девелоперской машине.